# VBA ListBox crashes when adding too long line

Tags: vba, listbox

I need to populate ListBox with lines (so I'm using 1 column without specified column width) by ListBox1.AddItem command. When the line is too long (about 10k characters :) ), Excel returns a runtime error '-2147352571 (80020005)': Type Mismatch.

When I was using TextBox, it worked correctly.

Moreover, how can I add horizontal scrollbar to the ListBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a 1,024 character limit on a listbox line. Could you populate an array where the input is chunked down to 1024 characters and then populate the listbox from the array?

Comment: that's it! thanks. couldn't come up with this trick b myself :) 
is there any chance to add horizontal scrollbar to the 1-column-ListBox?

Comment: Vertical scrollbars are automatic. For the horizontal scrollbar you will need to specify a ColumnWidth property that is greater than the width of the listbox.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But as I understand, it will be fixed width - even if all the lines are shorter. Is it possible to make a scroll-bar to adjust its width?

Comment: I suppose you could loop through the array and find the max length of the lines you have and use this to set the width e.g. Lst_Detail.Width = 72 prior to filling the listbox. The number refers to points. There are 72 points to the inch! You would need to play around with this to see what fits best with your line length

Comment: yeah, again, you are right, thanks. Hoped, there would be some native solution and didn't think out of the box to create such workaroud :)

Comment: The marked answer helped.  In PowerPoint with office 365 the listbox limit seems to be 2047 characters to a field.  Thanks for this insight.